# Unable to attach to remote geth: Invalid pipe address '/.rinkeby/geth.ipc'

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, myetherwallet, testnets, rinkeby

I'm on Windows and trying to connect to Ethereum Testnet via rinkeby.

I downloaded geth 1.8.2 and Ethereum Wallet 0.9.3

I gave 1st command as:

> geth --rinkeby --fast --cache=1024

NOTE: after above command, I get the `url` on cmd as:

> url=\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc

And 2nd command in another command prompt as:

> geth --datadir=./rinkeby attach

The same commands were working earlier.

I uninstalled both geth and Ethereum wallet and installed latest versions. I tried the commands on the earlier versions also where they were working but now they are not.

**I also tried connecting to Private net just now, but got the error message on 2nd command prompt as:**

> Unable to attach to remote geth: no known transport for URL scheme "c"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on Windoes or Linux?

Comment: @ismael i'm on Windows

Comment: Both `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc` and `geth attach \\.\pipe\geth.ipc` are working with geth v1.8.2. Will try to test with an older version later to verify if behavior has changed. If you are sure you should report the issue in go-ethereum issue tracker in github, so it is fixed.

Comment: @Ismael IMO, the issue is, earlier what I was getting after 1st command in cmd was: `url=\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc` but now I'm getting: `url=\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc`. So, i think that is why I'm getting the error as:  "Unable to attach to remote geth: Invalid pipe address '/.rinkeby/geth.ipc"

Comment: Is it something related to the environment variable??

Comment: The correct path on windows is `\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`. Perhaps geth is trying to 'escape' the backslash `\` (the backslash is a escape character in the go language).

Comment: @Ismael Yes I get that, But how to change that path.. We directly give `geth --rinkeby --fast --cache=1024` this command in Rinkeby or `geth --datadir=./chaindata --fast --cache=1024` this command in Private net. So where and how am I supposed to give that path? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure about testnetwork. But this below solution is easy go for private network. And it's working fine.

While running the geth node itself, specify the ipcpath. It will open the geth node, ipc and javascript console for you in single window. Try the below command.

```
geth --datadir ../../private-network/node1 \
      --networkid 2061 \(it should be same, if you are running multiple nodes)
      --port 30304 \ (should be different for every nodes)
      --nodiscover \
      --rpc \
      --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 \
      --rpcport 8504 \ (should be different for every nodes)
      --ipcpath ../../private-network/node1/geth.ipc \
      --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" \
      --etherbase 0xf628e41f3ca68341e9857102d4b3040aa418d763 \ (your coinbase account address)
      --verbosity 3 console
```

> One example for the given script.

```
geth --datadir=D:/Blockchain_Tech/node1 --networkid 2061 --port 30305 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8505 --ipcpath=D:/Blockchain_Tech/node1/geth.ipc --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" --etherbase 0x58ef18d5667552b4c0524b9a78cbf9493d2bd74a --verbosity 3 console
```

> Note:- This script is for MS-Windows.